# Grid-Like WrapPanel with resizable control in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, resizable, wrappanel

I want to make a grid with wrap panel behavior and resizable control inside it, how can I do this?
maybe it's easier to show what I want in images :

initial state:

[image]

resize control 1 with direction bottom-right so it will take around 2x2 cells, then control 2 and so on will rearrange it's position on the grid:

[image]

when it's resized back it should be back to initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to create a class that extends `Panel` to create the animations. Here is a [very good article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control) on how to create an animated `WrapPanel`. Then, you would need to create a `DataTemplate` for your items that uses `Trigger`s to grow and shrink each one. This could also be animated in the `Trigger`. The `Panel` would automatically move the other items around as the item changes size... dependent on the code you put in your `Panel.ArrangeOverride` method.

You would need to create a data type (class) to use as your items (squares). This class would need a string property to store the box number and a `bool` `IsLarge` property to let the UI know whether to display it large or not. I haven't actually tried this code, but you could use something like this for your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNameSpace:YourDataType}" x:Key="BoxTemplate">
    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Height="100" Width="100">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding YourTextProperty}" />
    </Border>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLarge}" Value="True"><!-- (A Boolean property) -->
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="200" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="200" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="200" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="200" To="100" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then you associate the `DataTemplate` with each `ListBoxItem` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="BoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource BoxTemplate}" />
    <Style.Resources><!-- this removes the default blue selection colour -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#00FFFAB0" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#00FFFAB0" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers><!-- comment this section out, or declare a SelectedBoxTemplate DataTemplate -->
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource SelectedBoxTemplate}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I haven't defined any `SelectedBoxTemplate` `DataTemplate`, but you could declare a different one that would get activated using the `Style.Trigger`.

Then finally, you would declare your `ListBox` something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BoxStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <YourXmlNameSpace:YourAnimationPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, actually the control (the one you suggest having an IsLarge property) inside the grid is manually resizable so the UI is quite interactive, so we don't the animation in the datatemplate cause we'll animate it ourself. I've tried to make the resizable control but i have no idea how to implement the wrapper (the custom panel u mentioned)

Comment: I provided a link to a very good article that shows how to do this... all you have to do is slightly adjust the code in the `Panel.MeasureOverride` and `Panel.ArrangeOverride` methods. Your code should end up very similar to the code in the example, although it will be slightly more complicated. The example code uses the largest `child.DesiredSize.Height` to determine the height of each row, but you will have to do more here to make sure that you can have two small boxes on each line that has one big one.